# Пишет, что имя не определено, хотя стоит input

Tags: python

[image: Где я накосячил?]

Я поставил input, и по идее, имя должно было приняться программой, но оно не принялось. Где я накосячил?

Comment: Вставляйте код в вопрос в виде текста, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

В питоне 2.7 используйте `raw_input("тут можно написать текст")`.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
```